# How to break a long string into multiple lines

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using this insert statement in my code in VBA Excel, but I'm not able to break it into more than one line:

```
SqlQueryString = "Insert into Employee values(" & txtEmployeeNo.Value & " _
,'" & txtContractStartDate.Value & "' _
,'" & txtSeatNo.Value & "' _
,'" & txtFloor.Value & "','" & txtLeaves.Value & "')"
```

It is giving error "Expected end of statement". How can I fix it?

Answer (score 59):

You cannot use the VB line-continuation character inside of a string.

```
SqlQueryString = "Insert into Employee values(" & txtEmployeeNo.Value & _
"','" & txtContractStartDate.Value &  _
"','" & txtSeatNo.Value & _
"','" & txtFloor.Value & "','" & txtLeaves.Value & "')"
```

Answer (score 15):

you may simply create your string in multiple steps, a bit redundant but it keeps the code readable and maintain sanity while debugging or editing

```
SqlQueryString = "Insert into Employee values(" 
SqlQueryString = SqlQueryString & txtEmployeeNo.Value & " ,"
SqlQueryString = SqlQueryString & " '" & txtEmployeeNo.Value & "',"
SqlQueryString = SqlQueryString & " '" & txtContractStartDate.Value & "',"
SqlQueryString = SqlQueryString & " '" & txtSeatNo.Value & "',"
SqlQueryString = SqlQueryString & " '" & txtContractStartDate.Value & "',"
SqlQueryString = SqlQueryString & " '" & txtSeatNo.Value & "',"
SqlQueryString = SqlQueryString & " '" & txtFloor.Value & "',"
SqlQueryString = SqlQueryString & " '" & txtLeaves.Value & "' )"
```

Answer (score 4):

If the long string to multiple lines confuses you. Then you may install mz-tools addin which is a freeware and has the utility which splits the line for you.

[Download Mz-tools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/download.aspx)

If your string looks like below

```
SqlQueryString = "Insert into Employee values(" & txtEmployeeNo.Value & "','" & txtContractStartDate.Value & "','" & txtSeatNo.Value & "','" & txtFloor.Value & "','" & txtLeaves.Value & "')"
```

Simply select the string > right click on VBA IDE > Select MZ-tools > Split Lines

[image]

Comment: seems like a neat tool. However, it has a 30 day free trial and the cheapest version to buy is $63.96. I do am quite lazy. But, I'm not so lazy that it would be worth $63.96 

Comment: @tomatoeshift Totally agree with you 

Comment: haha don't think any of us are $63.96 lazy @tomatoeshift