# Excel VBA How to break up very long URL for readability?

Tags: excel, vba, url

In VBA, I am passing a URL to Google Maps. After adding multiple Markers to the URL, the string becomes very very long and difficult to read.
I would like to break up the URL with a separate line for each Marker for readability.
VBA throws a hissy fit, the line break used for code (space underscore) does not get passed by the VBA compiler. HTML line breaks don't work either.
Example: `bot.Get "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/etc etc etc"`

Thank you for looking.

Comment: Its a little unclear what you are asking.  I assume that you are trying to build a URL but you could be parsing one.  Adding your  code would help bring context  to your question.

Comment: Did you also include an ampersand on each line?  Like this `& _` (ampersand space underscore)?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16636413/4717755)?

Comment: Aside from visually splitting the lines using line-breaks. You could also assemble the string by creating an array of strings, each item in the array being one part of the url, and then use `Join(myArray, "")`. This would let you work on each part of the url independently, before cleanly assembling the url for output.

Comment: The code is simple. The problem is getting a line break in the URL for readability.

Answer (score 1):

The following illustrates the idea of breaking long strings across multiple lines:

```
bot.Get "maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/…" & _
        "markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C62.107733,-145.541936" & _
        "markers=size:tiny%7Ccolor:green%7CDelta+Junction,AK" & _
        "markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0xFFFF00%7Clabel:C%7CTok,AK" & _
        "key=AIzaSyAhJIqOH3CNov_uZY2zPyqPBBrxorx2RN8"
```

Note that every line has double quotes, ampersands, and underscores.  Well, except for the last line.

Comment: Thank you. I copied and pasted that and VBA returns  Selenium error, invalid argument.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the URL itself.  Verify that the URL is valid.  The above code is just to show how to have multiple lines.